# Perl-Reading a file that matches a pattern having a variable

Tags: regex, perl, file

I want to read a file using perl that matches a pattern.  For Ex: Suppose i have a filename like Employee_20170412_2324.DAT where 20170412 is today's date in YYYYMMDD format and 2324 is the time in HHmm format.  I want to match all the files with .DAT extension in scripts directory that matches the file name Employee with today's date irrespective of the time. I have written the code snippet below:

`$fileday = date '+Y%M%d';
chomp $fileday;
$path = "mydir/scripts/";
$file = <$path/Employee_$fileday_*.DAT>;`

In the above code, $path is recognized as "mydir/scripts/" but $fileday is not recognized as today's date. It is taking as "$fileday" itself.  I would appreciate any help on this.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code has a few issues, the `date` was not formatted correctly, and no means for iterating files:

**Update 2** (using *strict* and *warnings*):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $fday = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime;
my $path = "mydir/scripts/Employee_" . $fday . "_" ;
my @file = glob "$path" .'[0-9]' x 4 . '.DAT';

say for @file;
```

Or you could even do the following to be non-date specific ...

```
my @list = glob "mydir/scripts/Employee_" . 
                '[0-9]' x 8 . '_' . 
                '[0-9]' x 4 . 
                '.DAT';

say for @list;
```

This is likely not the way people might normally do this, but it's a way —  and one that conforms.

**Result:**

```
mydir/scripts/Employee_20170412_2324.DAT
mydir/scripts/Employee_20170413_2325.DAT
mydir/scripts/Employee_20170413_2327.DAT
```

> ⌫ [deprecated : no strict/warning examples](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5be481f3be8f67b8add74ac2ea401319)

Comment: |@CoderHat: `glob` is *identical* to `<...>` except that it is clearer what is happening. `<FILEHANDLE>` is the same as `readline`, while `<=>` is the comparison operator, and they are easy to confuse.

Comment: @l'L'l: As above, because `<...>` is the same as `glob`, `my $scan = glob <"${file}_*.DAT">` is equivalent to `my $scan = glob glob qq/"$file_*.DAT"/`.

Comment: @l'L'l: There are still many issues with your code. I suggest that you test it. And ***always*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of *every* Perl program you write.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `%M` is the minute field; you need `%m` for the month

This will do what you need, but you need to be careful with the relative path `mydir/scripts` as it will give different results depending on the current directory when you run the program

```perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece;

my $path    = 'mydir/scripts';
my $pattern = localtime->strftime('Employee_%Y%m%d_*.DAT');

say $pattern;

my @files = glob "$path/$pattern";

say for @files;
```

#### output

This shows only the representation of `$pattern`. The list of files depends on your own system

```
Employee_20170412_*.DAT
```

Comment: @jm666: Are you worried about whitespace in the file names? Because there aren't any here. Anyway, it would be better to `use File::Glob ':bsd_glob'` to fix that. Adding quotes as you have done just gives the same problem with quotes instead of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Because I have always installed the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module, my soultion would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
use Path::Tiny;

my $t = localtime;
my $filepatt = $t->strftime("Employee_%Y%m%d_.*.DAT");

my $dirpath = path('mydir/scripts');
say for $dirpath->children( qr/^$filepatt$/ );
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

$fileday = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime;
print "time = ${fileday}\n";
$path = ".\\";
@files= <*$fileday*>; # for multiple files
foreach (@files) {
 print "$_  \n";
}
```

It will find multiple files:

```
time = 20170412
myfile_20170412_junk.dat
myfile_20170412_junk2.dat
```